# No audio when playing flutter app on mobile with just audio . Works ok with android emulator

Tags: android

Any of you clever developers know why I cannot play audio on my Galaxy mobile with flutter apps . Works fine on an emulator

The app I built works fine. Its a game that when the user completes the game a short 'success' mp3 plays. It works on the emulator but not on my Galaxy mobile. very strange!